# How to simple first person 3D camera in javascript?

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation

Is there function to draw rectangle in 3D in canvas. This function takes value x,y,depth,width,height. How to make function to move rectangle in vertical and horizontal when we have x,y,depth,width,height ? I have my script but not work. Here is:

```
function matrix(x,y,width,height,z,cont){
var x1=x,
y1=y,
z1=0;
x2=x+width+z,
y2=y+height+z,
z2=x+width+y+height+z;





   x11 = (Math.cos(Math.PI + cont) * x1) + (Math.cos(cont) * x1);
 
    y11 = (Math.cos(Math.PI + cont) * y1) + (Math.cos(cont) * y1);
 
    z11 = (Math.cos(Math.PI + cont) * z1) + (Math.cos(cont) * z1);
 
    x21  = (Math.cos(cont) * x2) + (Math.cos(Math.PI - cont) * x2);
 
    y21  = (Math.cos(cont) * y2) + (Math.cos(Math.PI - cont) * y2);
 
    z21  = (Math.cos(cont) * z2) + (Math.cos(Math.PI - cont) * z2);
    
    
    var 
width2=x21-x11-z,
height2=y21-y11-z;
z2=z21-z11;


    ctx.reset();            
draw_rectangle(Math.round(x11),Math.round(y11),Math.round(width2),Math.round(height2),Math.round(z2));
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all about transformate this pattern:

```
x1=x*cos(cont)-y*sin(cont)
y1=x*sin(cont)+y*cos(cont)
```

pattern work that:

[image]

I want that:

[image]

this video show what i want exacly:

https://testy.vot.pl/zadanie/w2.mp4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have solution. First will be variable x to subtract on device width daily pass 2. Next variable y to subtract device height. This solution calculate pattern:

```
x1=x*cos(cont)-y*sin(cont)
y1=x*sin(cont)+y*cos(cont)
```

in coordinate system. Next return to variable in first character. Well add x width device width daily pass 2 and y add device height. So pattern will be like this:

```
var nx;
var ny;
var ox=devicewidth/2;
var oy=deviceheight;



nx=Math.round(((tablex[i3]-ox)*Math.cos(kont*Math.PI/180))-((tabley[i3]-oy)*((Math.sin(kont*Math.PI/180)))));
ny=Math.round(((tablex[i3]-ox)*Math.sin(kont*Math.PI/180))+((tabley[i3]-oy)*((Math.cos(kont*Math.PI/180)))));


tablex[i3]=nx+ox;
tabley[i3]=ny+oy;
```

And will be work.